# how to make windows file explorer to show files top to down in tiles rather than left to right`

Tags: windows, windows-10

tile1 tile2 tile3 tile4

to

tile1

tile2

tile3

tile4

[from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqLWP.png)
[==>to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y289T.png)

it would look nice if the tiles or other formats look top to down rather than left to right.

Answer (score 0):

[image: you can change it directly from the bottom bar as i show you in image]

[image: or you can click on top bar on view then choose ditals]

you can change it directly from the bottom bar as i show you in the first image
or you can click on top bar on view then choose ditals as i show you in second image

Comment: i wanted to know if it was possible to do in tile view only